# dropdown Value hide

Tags: angular, typescript

```html
<div fxFlex="25" fxFlex.xs="100" class="px-8">
    <div class="form-label">Ticket Status <span class="reqSgnColor">*</span>
    </div>
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
        <mat-select matNativeControl required formControlName="complaint_status" filter="true" id="comp_status"
            name="comp_status" (valueChange)="closed_over_by($event)">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let status of complnt_status" [value]="status.value">{{status.viewValue}}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
        <mat-error> Select Status is Required</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

[image]

Basically I have 2 pages, in one page i need to hide a value from dropdown, and show the same value in other Page of the the dropdown. actually i have two pages "Open-Complain" and another is "Resolve-Complaints" so in that i have a button called edit button (Present on both pages Identical).When i go on Page "Open-Complants" in Drop down "Close Option" shoulnt appear and in Case of "Resolve-Complaints" in drop down "open option shouldnt be there".on NOte When Click Edit Button Both Comes On "Edit Complaint Page only".option are static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On event when changing route to the other page, modify the array complnt_status that would solve the problem for drop down options.

```
const indexOfObject = complnt_status.findIndex((object) => {
  return object.viewValue === 'Close';
});

if (indexOfObject !== -1) {
  complnt_status.splice(indexOfObject, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An easy and quick solution is to create two complnt_status arrays in the two different ".ts" files, i.e.

For Open Complaints component use

```
complnt_status: Complaintstatus[] = [ 
    {value: 1, viewvalue: 'Open'}, 
    {value: 2, viewvalue: 'Resolved'}, 
    {value: 4, viewvalue: 'Auto-Resolution'} 
];
```

And for Resolve Complaints component use

```
complnt_status: Complaintstatus[] = [ 
    {value: 2, viewvalue: 'Resolved'}, 
    {value: 3, viewvalue: 'Close'}, 
    {value: 4, viewvalue: 'Auto-Resolution'} 
];
```